# Sharepoint comments module best approach

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement to make a comments web part that allows paging. Paging is a common feature throughout the design.

What I was wondering was is a web part the best way of going about this or is there another approach that would be more suited to sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking... but the Linq To SharePoint functionality in SharePoint 2010 features the Skip/Take functionality which can provide paging for lists, if that is where your data is being persisted. If you have data being persisted to a database, you can use obviously use the Linq Skip/Take functionality.

Not sure if that helps

Comment: Open to all suggestions. Would you have created a webpart for comments and a user control for the paging control or how would you have went about architecting it?